# How can I apply CSS to an HTML text input?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is the ASP.Net MVC2 code that I use to display a textbox input.

```
<div id="blackbar">
    <p>Sistema de Evaluaciones de Docentes</p>
    <%: Html.TextBox("termino","") %>
    <img src="../../Content/search.png" alt="search" />
</div>
```

Here is how it renders:

```
<div id="blackbar">
    <p>Sistema de Evaluaciones de Docentes</p>
    <input id="termino" name="termino" type="text" value="" />
    <img src="../../Content/search.png" alt="search" />
</div>
```

How would I use CSS for example to give the textbox a red border? How can I tell MVC2 to give this text input a class or something?

**EDIT:
I've tried the following, but the text I write into the input isn't green.**

```
.textinput
{
    color:Green;
}

<%: Html.TextBox("termino", "", new { @class = "textinput" })%>
```

Comment: You could style this `input` by targeting the ID? eg. `#termino {}` in your CSS. Or are you wanting to apply/remove this style from a few elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%=Html.TextBox("termino", "", new { @class = "redborder" }) %>
```

Comment: +1 for answering the second part of the question (I have no experience of ASP/MVC2, so could only answer how to style after it's generated).

Comment: Nevermind, I was loading the CSS file from cache. MASSIVE thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#termino { border: solid 1px #F00; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[name=termino],
input#termino,
#termino
{
border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To style all text boxes in the blackbar div you can use:

```
#blackbar input[type='text'] { ... }
```